# what does resolve or subscriber really mean in a promise or observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I want to clear my doubts about promises and observables. I know that promises and observables are used to write asynchronous code. But, can I use them to get notified when an array or a string changes? For example, in Angular I have a service and a component. The service has an array and a promise:

```
export class MainService{
 data: number[]=[1,2,3] 
 dataPromise(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{resove(this.data)})
 }
 pushData(number: number) {
  this.data.push(number)
 }
}
```

And, the component is getting this promise on ngOnInit and setting one of its variables to the array of the service returned by the promise:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 componentData: number[];
 constructor(private mainService: MainService){}
 ngOnInit(){
  this.mainService.dataPromise.then((data:number[])=>{this.componentData = data})
 }
 onClick(){
  this.mainService.pushData(4)
 }
}
```

So, if we connect the function onClick() with some HTML and trigger it, 4 is added to the data array on the service. And, if I update the array in the service, then the promise returning this array in my components ngOnInit() will trigger again and give me the updated array which is [1,2,3,4]. Which then I set using componentData=data. But, for some reason, if I have a string instead of an array, the promise isn't resolving again with the new value of the string in my component. This is weird because when I changed the array, the promise did resolve the new value. So, what's the reason? Can I use a promise or observable to watch for changes on an array or a string? I know that I can do this using EventEmitter or subjects. But, I want to know what the resolve in promises is really giving us and if the promise resolves the array or the string again automatically whenever they change.

Answer (score 1):

> If i update the array in the service the promise sending this array to which i am listening with `then` will triggers again and and gives me the new updated array

No, absolutely not. A promise only resolves once, point. It does not trigger again, and it does not even notice that the array is updated.

The real distinction between an array and a string is that the former is a mutable object while the latter is an immutable primitive value. In your example code, both `this.mainService.data` and `this.componentData` refer to exactly the same array instance. Pushing a new value to it will modify that shared array, regardless whether you do it through `this.componentData.push(4)`, `this.mainService.data.push(4)` or `this.mainService.pushData(4)`. It's Angular that somehow picks up this change.

Yes, you can however use an observable for this, which *can* trigger multiple times. You'll need to use this for your string data, and in your `pushData` method you will need explicitly put the new value into the observable then.